# Setup Apache reverse-proxy for rails app running at port 3000

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I manage a small VPS running several PHP/MySQL websites. It's running CentOS (albeit a slightly modified VSP version x86). All is working well.
However, now I would like to run a Rails 3 application on a certain domain hosted on my VPS. The thing is, the application requires Rails 3 which isn't yet supported by cPanel. 
If I ssh to the server and run `rails s` in the app's folder it runs smoothly, and I can access it at `siegedog.com:3000`. However, I would like to redirect all requests to `siegedog.com` to port 3000.

I've read that this would assume setting up a reverse proxy that would redirect all the requests it gets for siegedog to Mongrel, which should be running on port 3000. I've checked out a lot of tutorials but most of them were confusing and/or quite out-of-date.

I have also tried Passenger. However, editing my httpd.conf is disallowed by cpanel. So I used a separate file that gets included there and added the extra configuration parameters in a remote file, only to get the `Default server page` problem, and no errors in the apache error log.

Comment: What "Default server page" error is this? Could you take a a screenshot and show us?

Comment: Something like this: http://static.howtoforge.com/images/lamp_installation_ubuntu6.06/apache_home.jpg (this is for an older version of Apache) It's usually a sign that httpd.conf is misconfigured.

Comment: Have you tried putting the configuration in a `.htaccess` file in the document root directory?

Comment: Hehe, it's working now! I disabled the redirect now, will re-enable it when signup on the app gets a bit safer! :D Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, thanks to John Douthat's I managed to do set up my app pretty easily using the following .htaccess document:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^siegedog\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.siegedog\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) "http\:\/\/127\.0\.0\.1\:3000\/$1" [P,L]
```

Also, to start it from an ssh connection I called:

```
nohup rails s &
```

in the rails application's root. 
All is well now!